# Ubuntu 20.04 Password

Tags: 20.04, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed a wsl Ubuntu 20.04. I entered a username, but it will not let me type in a password. It just will not let me type anything. Can somebody give me the explanation for this?

Comment: Ubuntu does not show the password in the terminal for extra security (it does not even show asterix). You can write down the password and press enter, and it should just work.

Comment: Yes it  did. Thank you. I got the password in. I made a suggestion on GitHub to add that fact to Microsoft Docs. I didn't see it there.